# She's gone now, so you'll have to wait

Tags: word-usage, american-english

I know that this question sounds really bizarre.  This is a situation I once witnessed.

There's just one restroom. There are three girls there. Two girls are waiting their turn. One of them leaves and comes back after a little bit. She is informed by the third person who was present there:

> The girl who was waiting here has gone (to the restroom) now, so you'll have to wait.

Can "to the restroom" part be dropped, and just "she's gone now" be used?

Comment: It could work as part of formality, but might also change the context. e.g. She's gone momentarily or for a longer period of time, how long should you wait?

Comment: There's nothing bizarre about this question or that sentence, although the question could've been written more clearly: there are three girls, A and B waiting outside while C is inside. B leaves, and while she's gone, C goes out and A goes in. Now B returns and the conversation takes place between B and someone else.

Comment: So @user2684291 does it sound fine? Or does that part "to the restroom" have to be included? (P.S. I'll be more precise next time.)

Comment: If they are waiting to use the toilet, the bystander could say "The other girl has gone _in_ now." "She's gone" would imply that she had gone away. But the situation is so familiar that there is no need to explain all the details. If it was felt to be necessary to say _anything_, "I'm afraid you've lost your place in the queue" would be sufficient.